# Attribute value when attribute name is a variable

Tags: xml, xslt

Let's say I have a variable in an XSL sheet like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="myID" select="."/>
```

And assume that 'myID' holds an existing attribute name of an XML tag. I want to be able to access the value of that attribute in another file with the same attribute name.

I've tried this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="@$myID"/>
```

But that doesn't appear to work. What is the proper way to access the value of an attribute with a variable name?

Comment: Please review: [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XPath: *"Of all the attributes, pick the one with the name equal to `$myID`"*

```
<xsl:value-of select="@*[name() = $myID]"/>
```